# Read all bytes from a ReadableStream

Tags: javascript

I'd like to load an entire [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) response in one go, but there doesn't seem to be a `readAll` or similar function.

What is the most performant way to read every byte from a [ReadableStreamDefaultReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader) into a single [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)?

Comment: would `response.arrayBuffer()` do what you need?

Comment: Damn, I walked right by that one.  Post that as the answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fetch's `Response` interface has [`.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) which returns an `ArrayBuffer`.